# Fade-out controls when there's no keyboard/mouse input

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, fadeout

Based on this [script](http://jsfiddle.net/AMn9v/) I found on Stack Overflow, I tried adapting it to fade out an editor  panel on a HTML page. Fading out works fine, but I'd like limit the fade-out from being triggered.

What I hope to accomplish is to prevent the fade-out whenever the mouse is over the editor panel (and child controls) or when there's keyboard activity in one of the input children.

```
var i = null;

// this part is working
$("#my-canvas").mousemove(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
    $("#panel,#btn-panel-toggle,#fps").fadeIn(200);
    var i = setTimeout('$("#panel,#btn-panel-toggle,#fps").fadeOut(800);', 3000);
})

// this part is not working
$("#panel").mouseover(function() {
    clearTimeout(i);
})
```

For a live example, please check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/idleberg/axqHE/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two independent variables are needed here to indicate, whether the `input#sc-url` is focused and `div#panel` is hovered by mouse or not. Then you can handle the timer with these functions:

```js
$(function () {

    var t = null; //timer
    var is_url_focused = false, is_panel_hovered = false;
    var panel = $('#panel');

    function hide_panel(){
        if (t) {
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
        t = setTimeout(function(){
            if (is_url_focused || is_panel_hovered) {
                return;
            }
            panel.stop().animate({
                opacity:0
            },800, function(){
                panel.hide(); // == diplay:none
            });
        },2000);
    }

    function show_panel(){
        panel.show().stop().animate({
            opacity:1
        },800);
    }

    $('#my-canvas').mouseenter(function(){
        show_panel();
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        hide_panel();
    });
    $('#panel').hover(function(){
        is_panel_hovered = true;
        show_panel();
    }, function(){
        is_panel_hovered = false;
        hide_panel();
    });
    $('#sc-url').focus(function(){
        is_url_focused = true;
        show_panel();
    }).blur(function(){
        is_url_focused = false;
        hide_panel();
    });
    $('#btn-panel-toggle').click(function(){
        if (panel.is(':hidden')) {
            panel.css('opacity',1).show();
        } else {
            panel.css('opacity',0).hide();
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w9dv4/3/

Comment: this works almost as desired. however, it only initialises after the pointer has been over the panel. also, after hiding it only shows when hovering over the panel (not the entire canvas). i've tried some stuff, but nothing worked as desired.

Comment: it's true, i want the editor panel to stay visible while someone is using it. however, if someone never uses the editor in the first place, it should as well fade out. once faded out, any mouse movement on the (fullsize) canvas should fade it in (otherwise one has to know where the hidden panel is).

Comment: Probably understand, thanks for clarifying! So the panel should only appear, when the mouse is over canvas.

Comment: 1. initially, everything is shown

2. the panel fades out all the time, except when it's in use (mouse/keyboard activity)

3. a hidden panel always comes back when the mouse is moved (anywhere on the screen)

it's probably obvious, once you looked at my [real-world example](http://webvs.visbot.net/params.html)